# HTML Canvas - text-shadow not working on Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is the code:

```
var surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    if (surface.getContext) {
      var context = surface.getContext('2d');

      context.shadowOffsetX = 2;
      context.shadowOffsetY = 2;
      context.shadowBlur = 5;
      context.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";

      context.textBaseline = "top";
      context.font = "125px helvetica";
      context.textAlign = "center";

      var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(22,28,106)");
      gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(19,25,98)");

      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillText("Some Title", 450, 10);
}
```

the shadow just looks like a 1px outline... any ideas?

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/MDgR3/

Comment: Looks good: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/MDgR3/

Comment: @Šime Vidas are you seeing a shadow on the text in that jsfiddle?  I'm not...

Comment: @jtm My insinuation was that it works in my browser, but not in yours `:)` I'm using Chrome 10...

Comment: @Šime Vidas im running chrome 10.0.648.205, and I don't see a text-shadow...

Comment: @jtm I see this: http://i.imgur.com/QCth8.png

Comment: http://cl.ly/2p091G2I3Z2W1V0u1q3O thats what it looks like to me... no shadow.

Comment: @jtm Maybe it's a Mac/Win issue (I'm on Win7). Otherwise, I'm clueless.

Comment: @jtm I see the shadow in IE9, O11, FF4 and Ch10, but **not** in Safari 5.

Comment: @Šime Vidas thanks, perhaps it is a mac thing. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Check out the bottom example here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/  There I see a shadow in safari. Just pushing that along.

Comment: You can also try using CSS3 for example: text-shadow: #FFF 1px 1px 1px;

However this will still have some problems, because it is not compatible with IE, but definately works on Mac's with Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @ryan Canvas elements don't take css properties.

Comment: This appears to be a documented webkit bug that has since been fixed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15266

Comment: @matt thanks for this link. I just tested this in ff4, and the shadow is showing up.  When tested in WebKit r84622, there is still no shadow. This may be a webkit bug.

Comment: I'm in Chrome 12 on OSX – no shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like safari is broken. If you remove the gradient code then safari correctly adds the text shadow:

http://jsfiddle.net/hv5zR/1/

If you draw the shadow and then draw the gradient over the top it works in safari.... this is a horrible hack but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/nUbZX/

Comment: Nice! I submitted this as a bug to the webkit team.  This should not be the only way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was just fixed by the following commit:
http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/188148